# How To Fix This Function In PHP

Tags: php, function

I Want To insert in sql with this function but this not work, any idea to fix this

the error is  Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\WampServer\www\test.php on line 29

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
    $Connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pytshqip');
    $contact_method = 'aaaaa';

    $form_data = array
    (
        'text' => $contact_method,
        'from' => $contact_method,
        'user_1' => $contact_method,
        'user_2' => $contact_method,
        'date' => time()
    );

    dbRowInsert('chat', $form_data);

    function dbRowInsert($table_name, $form_data)
    {
        // retrieve the keys of the array (column titles)
        $fields = array_keys($form_data);

        // build the query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name."
        (`".implode('`,`', $fields)."`)
        VALUES('".implode("','", $form_data)."')";

        // run and return the query result resource
        return mysqli_query($Connection, $sql);
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here date is of which type. It seems to be integer..

Comment: Undefined variable `$Connection` in `dbRowInsert`.

Comment: variable scope, that's it. `$Connection` is defined outside the function

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is outside function scope. Add `global $Connection;` in your `dbRowInsert()` function before you use `$Connection` to be able to access the variable in function scope.

Answer (score 0):

As you use the variable $Connection, which has been defined outside the function dbRowInsert(), you need to use the global keyword.

```
function dbRowInsert($table_name, $form_data)
{
    global $Connection;

    // retrieve the keys of the array (column titles)
    $fields = array_keys($form_data);

    // build the query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name."
    (`".implode('`,`', $fields)."`)
    VALUES('".implode("','", $form_data)."')";

    // run and return the query result resource
    return mysqli_query($Connection, $sql);
}
```

You can find more information here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php